# How to get standard URI connection string (without srv) on mongodb website with current update?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have made a cluster on mongodb website, whitelisted IP adress, added the user and connected my application, but it is not giving me 'Standard URI connection' option (maybe their website got updated) instead it is giving me one with `srv`. So when I used it in mongoose.connect() function it is giving me error:"Invalid Uri,Must begin with mongodb://"...

I have been working to connect to mongodb for so long but failing every time

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have created cluster on MongoDB Atlas? Right.

If using mongo application:
change nodejs version to 2.12 or later from connect your application screen.

[image]

If using mongo shell:

On the "Connect to Cluster0" page, select I have mongo shell installed, then select mongo shell version "3.4 or earlier". You will get the desired format.

[image]

Comment: I am using mongodb atlas but not mongodb shell as connection method instead I am using "Connect your Application"

Comment: Then choose, connect your application from connect screen, and change nodejs version 2.2.12 or later